# libpng errors not being caught by try/catch block

Tags: c++, opencv, libpng

I am using OpenCV's imdecode() function. When I pass a partial image, it prints to screen saying "libpng error: PNG input buffer is incomplete". I tried putting that in a try/catch block but I still see that being printed. How do I handle such errors?

Comment: Sounds like it prints directly to error stream. This has nothing to do with exceptions and thus nothing to do with `try/catch` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libpng by default prints error messages to stderr.  But you can supply your own
replacement error handler to do whatever you want with the error messages.  See the explanation (look for "user_error_fn) in the libpng-manual.txt file that is distributed with libpng.

You don't need to rebuild libpng to do that; simply put your replacement handler in your own source code along with a pointer to it in your png_create_read_struct() call.

Comment: I am not using libpng directly, but using another library (opencv) that depends on libpng. So would this still be possible to do?

Comment: If your application calls png_create_read_struct(), then it's possible for you to do.  If opencv does not replace the error handler with its own and then give you the ability to replace that, then no.  I don't see anything in the documentation at docs.opencv.org indicating that using a custom error handler is possible.

Comment: I searched the libpng source for "buffer is incomplete" and came up empty.  So I guess the application, rather than libpng, is calling png_error().

Answer (score 0):

Those errors are shown because it prints directly to the output, no exception is thrown. Note that libpng is developed in C, not C++.

To remove this message, you pretty much must edit the libpng source code and recompile it.

There is only one thing else you could try: maybe libpng prints it to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. If so, you can redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` or something else.